# $Z_2 $ topological index in spin liquid

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-order

What is $Z_2 $ topological index in spin liquid system? How to understand its physical picture in condensed matter?

Comment: Are you taking about the orientation dependence of the ground state?

Comment: As written in the answer below, there are no such index for spin liquids (as there is for time-reversal invariant topological insulators). Are you thinking about the so-called $\mathbb Z_2$ spin liquids? The $\mathbb Z_2$ does not refer to a topological index, but rather to the fact that the low-energy dynamics are described by a $\mathbb Z_2$ gauge theory. There are also so-called $SU(2)$ and $U(1)$ spin liquids. See http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0107071 for a partial classification.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the the $ Z_2 $ spin liquids. Thanks for your answer and reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different spin liquids are extremely rich, and they cannot be described by
$Z_2$ topological index. So there is no $Z_2$ topological index for generic
spin liquids.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is down-voted, since its 100 % correct.